# Ubuntu 17.10 DNS setup

Tags: server, 17.10, dns, systemd

Will try to make this understandable.
Originally had Ubuntu 16.04 (server version) setup with dnsmasq and ipvanish
This was so i could run all my devices in my house through the ubuntu server vpn - Ubuntu ip was 192.168.0.10 - Connecting devices was setup with gateway and dns as IP 192.168.0.10 - all worked except i had dns leaks eg: was using dns servers from my vpn and also what was in network/interfaces.
I upgraded to 17.10 in the hope dns leak issue would be resolved but now i have the issue that i cannot use the server ip as the DNS on clients i have to manually input the vpn dns on clients for internet to work.Isnt the new system systemd to replace the function of dnsmasq and if so what am i missing that should be setup. dnsmasq worked as soon as it was installed on 16.04 with no setup.In both setups i am using the server version not Network Manager

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 17.10 they changed to netplan to manage networks.

for desktop it is now netplan/networkmanager
for server (headerless) it is now netplan/networkd

So basically anything you have edited doesn't really work anymore.

As far as I understand you now edit gui from within the gui (I don't use the gui), if you google ubuntu 18.04 static ip netplan networkd you will probably find what you are looking for. I have only just discovered most of this, and I am still not 100% sure how it all works, which is why I have not told you how I setup my network stuff. Bad advise only makes things worse.

My key info was found here: https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/